# NPE when generating graph using SchemaCrawler Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, database-schema, schemacrawler

I want to generate DB schema graph using SchemaCrawler and it's Maven plugin. I don't want to use constructions like

```
java -classpath ../_schemacrawler/lib/*:lib/* ...
```

because it must be universal. I want to use Maven for all dependencies and users will only execute something like:

```
mvn schemacrawler:schemacrawler
```

or even a small bash script wrapping this command.

But I'm getting NullPointerException when executing. Part of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.schemacrawler</groupId>
            <artifactId>schemacrawler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>qwerty</password>
                <infolevel>maximum</infolevel>
                <command>details</command>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.35</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When executing

```
mvn schemacrawler:schemacrawler -e
```

I'm getting:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   net.sourceforge.schemacrawler:schemacrawler-maven-plugin:9.5:schemacrawler
>   (default-cli) on project my-project: Execution default-cli of goal
>   net.sourceforge.schemacrawler:schemacrawler-maven-plugin:9.5:schemacrawler
>   failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   net.sourceforge.schemacrawler:schemacrawler-maven-plugin:9.5:schemacrawler
>   (default-cli) on project my-project: Execution default-cli of goal
>   net.sourceforge.schemacrawler:schemacrawler-maven-plugin:9.5:schemacrawler
>   failed.   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
>   default-cli of goal
>   net.sourceforge.schemacrawler:schemacrawler-maven-plugin:9.5:schemacrawler
>   failed.   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     ... 19 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   java.io.File.(File.java:277)    at
>   org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     ... 20 more

Please help me - how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) to execute SchemaCrawler from within Maven, instead of the SchemaCrawler plugin. Unfortunately, the SchemaCrawler Maven plugin is not being maintained at this time.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)